# Allow Google Drive API to Run Locally (Not on a Webserver)

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I came across this feature request, and it pretty accurately summarizes what I'm trying to accomplish: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=46

Is there any kind of a workaround to allow the Google Drive API to post files from a local execution?  I should also note, this javascript code will be running locally on an Android device, so it's not as simple as just setting up a localhost on my PC, such as with xampp.

Answer (score 1):

There are no workarounds for the moment, file origins are being rejected.